# Integrating Payment Option In Android

Tags: android, paypal, payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing

I am working on an application which requires payment options for the user. User can do the payment by two options

1. PayPal
2. InternetBanking (Debit or Credit card)

This is my first time working on payment feature. To integrate PayPal I can use their SDK. But would like to get more information on implementing NetBanking in Android.

It will be very helpful for me to get started if anyone can share some links to get some idea on how it works and how to implement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I am working for payment options using Paytm and here in India it is a good option, however there documentation is not good.

WHat they are doing is, they gave me two PHP files which i Have to deploy in my server, one is inChecksumGenerationURL and second one is inChecksumVerificationURL and they provided an android SDK to initialize there SDK.

now After calling these two URL's using their Callback Function , they will redirect me to their activtity they provided me in their SDK.

and their will come two options, one of Debit/Credit card payment and one is NetBanking Payment.

What they are doing in NetBanking option is that, they are redirecting us to Banks website and after successfull payment they are coming back to our app using callback URL.

For netbanking You have to provide a callback URL.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. One question - what will happen if the user does not have paytm app in the their device. Will it still work ? Since the Paytm SDK will launch Paytm Activity as per your comment.

Comment: Yes, that's why they are providing SDK for android studio.

Comment: It's very easy to implement Paytm payment gateway into android app.

Answer (score 1):

If you are from US, PayPal got it covered for both options, PayPal account or credit card payment.

The [PayPal Mobile SDKs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/mobile-sdk-overview/) we provided for both iOS and Android platform can easily cover both the options.

Please have a look/read on the details [HERE](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/README.md) if you are interested on implementing PayPal Android SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If PayPal is providing for the options then its wonderful. But I am not from US so as per your comment I cannot use paypal for both right ?

Comment: @ikr024 May I know where you are from then?

Comment: @ik024 The credit card option on the SDK won't work for India Accounts, I am sorry for that.

Comment: Hey, question - I am build an app for client in US, credit card option should  work in this scenario right ?